# SQL - list of merged contend of two (joined) tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

team,

i am currently lost ..

what i wanna do is a kind of `JOIN`, however a `SELECT` using a `JOIN` will skip rows when the condition is emty ...

an `UNION` will end in an error-message as the select over T1 comes with 4 and T2 with 2 lines in my example below:

```
T1: Name        Ort
---------------------- 
Markus      München 
Christian   Berlin 
Hubert      Frankfurt 
Kalle       Düsseldorf

T2
Ort         Anmerkung
-----------------------
München     Bayern
Frankfurt   Hessen
```

Outcome what i wanna archive are all 4 lines from T1 including the information from T2 (when exists) - compared/joined over "Ort".

```
Result:
T1.Name     T1.Ort      T2.Anmerkung
------------------------------
Markus      München     Bayern
Christian   Berlin      
Hubert      Frankfurt   Hessen
Kalle       Düsseldorf
```

Comment: correct same solution. 
my search in the forum did not route me to -> "..join with another table, allowing nulls". 
honestly, even whe soution is same the question would not point direct to the same from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. It will keep records from the first table that don't have a corresponding row in the second table.

```
select t1.name, t1.ort, t2.anmerkung
from t1
left join t2 on t1.ort=t2.ort
```

Comment: many thanks Kristjan .. 
i had a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp , but did not see the solution on the left side. 
great, many thansk again!

Comment: Happy to help. :D Since you are new at this site, we encurage you to upvote/accept answers that help you. That way good and helpful answers are distinguished and are more likely to help other users with similar problems to solve.